# javax.inject does not exists

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

To investigate troubles with `javax.inject` I have created minimalistic Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA.

It contains `Main.java` only:

```
import javax.inject.Scope;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

and settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'test'
```

Building the project I got

> Error:(1, 20) java: package javax.inject does not exist

What's wrong with javax, why it doesn't exists??

Hmm, it seems the problem is not specifically with javax. Tried to add different dependencies from mavenCentral, no one works. Like Gradle does not load external libraries at all.

**Solved**

The problem was with `repositories` - it must be outside of `buildscript`.

Comment: I use `javax.inject` in gradle [here](https://github.com/uklance/tiny-ioc/blob/master/build.gradle#L19) perhaps it'll help?

Answer (score 13):

Just bring the `javax.inject` dependency

```
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Compile only dependencies are distinctly different than regular “compile” dependencies. They are not included on the runtime classpath and are non-transitive, meaning they are not included in dependent projects. This is true when using Gradle project dependencies and also when publishing to Maven or Ivy repositories. In the latter case, compile only dependencies are simply omitted from published metadata.

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: Tried with compile instead of compileOnly - still the same error.

Comment: compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

Comment: "Cannot resolve external dependency javax.inject:javax.inject:1 because no repositories are defined" - something wrong with gradle.